# Android - need help for ondraw() sample

Tags: java, android

i've used below code for draw a view

```
@Override
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR);

        final RectF rectl = new RectF(0,0,2* padding,getHeight());
        final RectF rectr = new RectF(getWidth()-(2* padding),0,getWidth(),getHeight());

        canvas.drawLine(padding, 0, getWidth()-padding, 0, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(padding,getHeight()-1, getWidth()-padding, getHeight()-1, paint);
        canvas.drawArc(rectl, 90, 180, true, paint);
        canvas.drawArc(rectr, 270, 180, true, paint);
    }
```

The output is like below

[image]

but i expect, need to remove the drawArc bottom line , like this,

[image]

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the 3rd argument of drawArc to false.

useCenter means that the center of the arc should also be connected to the ends, the difference between a semicircle and a D.

Comment: Hi thanks. its working now. unable to accept answer now. i'll accept it after 4 mins.

Comment: hi i need another help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572371/android-need-help-for-ondraw-view-sample