# Android - need help for ondraw() view sample

Tags: java, android

i've used below code for draw a view

```
@Override

protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    RectF rectF = new RectF(0,0,30,30);
    RectF rectF1 = new RectF(200,0,230,30);
    canvas.drawArc(rectF, 270, 180, false, paint);
    canvas.drawArc(rectF1, 90, 180, false, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(15, 0, 215, 0, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(15, 30, 215,30, paint);

}
```

The output is like below

[image]

but i want fill the color inside the view.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Path instead of calling four times drawLine/drawArc

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my ondraw code . Now its working.

```
Path path = new Path();
path.arcTo(rectF, 270, 180);
        path.lineTo(200,30 );
        path.arcTo(rectF1, 90, 180);
        path.close();
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Comment: dont create Path object inside onDraw, do it in View constructor

Answer (score 0):

```
paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
```

Good luck.